# Filter search results with elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I'm using the following PHP client for elasticsearch: https://github.com/nervetattoo/elasticsearch, but I'm having trouble adding multiple fields to match against in my search query.

I want to add a filter by type option if one has been set.

I've played with this syntax, but only the first field specified is taken into account when searching.

```
$type = ($type) ? $type : false;

$options = array(
            'fields' => array('title', 'content', 'profile_id', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'date', 'url'),
            'from' => 0,
            'size' => 10,
            'query' => array(
                ($type ?
                    array('match' => array('name' => $term, 'type' => $type)) :
                    array('match' => array('_all' => $term))
                )
            )
        );
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "only the first field is taken into account"? Can you bemore specific?

Answer (score 0):

If anybody is interested, I solved it using the bool flag and tweaking syntax.

```
$options = array(
   'fields' => array('title', 'content', 'profile_id', 'type', 'name', 'description', 'date', 'url'),
   'from' => 0,
   'size' => 10,
   'query' => array(
      ($type ?
          array(
              'bool' => array(
                  'must' => array(
                      array('term' => array('_all' => $term)),
                      array('term' => array('type' => $type))
                   )
              )
          ) :
            array('match' => array('_all' => $term))
    )
  )
);
```